# Retrofit 404 not found web api

Tags: android, azure, http-status-code-404, retrofit

I have a web api and an application. So I want to a Register app but I have a problem. I use the azure.
There is my registerapi (interface)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/application/json")
public void insertUser(
        @Field("Username") String Username,
        @Field("Password") String Password,
        @Field("Email") String Email,
        Callback<Response> callback);
```

and my mainactivty.java page

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private Button buttonRegister;
final public static String ROOT_URL = "http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmail);
    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnkayit);
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            insertUser();
        }
    });
}
private void insertUser()
{
    RestAdapter adapter =new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();
    RegisterAPI api = adapter.create(RegisterAPI.class);
    api.insertUser(
            editTextUsername.getText().toString(),
            editTextPassword.getText().toString(),
            editTextEmail.getText().toString(),
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    String output = "";
                    try{
                        reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                        output=reader.readLine();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
};
```

and I get retrofit 404 not found.

Comment: Remove the first /, @POST("application/json") and check that the enpoint exists http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register/application/json

Comment: ı try this so ı get eror this :> retrofit eror "application/json" must start with "/"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register` is the url to your register method in your API:

A 404 means there is no API for this url.
Your baseurl is `http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register`
After this baseurl the path inside the @post is appended. This will result in the url: `http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register/application/json`.
The url to your register method is probably the first url.
The baseurl should the url to the root url of your api, in your case this probably is: `http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/`. In the @GET, @POST, @PUT you set the path to a specific api method. In your case that would be `@POST("music/register")`. You don't set the type of data that is sent to the API in here.

Comment: ı change to http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/music/register so ı do http://bsapmusic.azurewebsites.net/api/ and ı do @POST("/music/register") thanks man