# retrofit error code 404 using Multipart Post method

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to upload two videos and some text fields into the retrofit library 
using Multipart Post method, How to Send Value using the android retrofit library

API Interface

```
 @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @Multipart
    @POST("event")
    Call<ResponsePojo> submitData(@Part MultipartBody.Part video,
                                  @Part("device_id") String device_id,
                                  @Part("lat") String lat,
                                  @Part("lng") String lng,
                                  @Part("speed") String speed,
                                  @Part("event_type") String event_type,
                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part videolarge);
```

ResponsePoja model Class

```
public class ResponsePojo {

    @SerializedName("fileData")
    @Expose
    private String fileData;

    @SerializedName("device_id")
    @Expose
    private String device_id;

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("lng")
    @Expose
    private String lng;

    @SerializedName("speed")
    @Expose
    private String speed;

    @SerializedName("event_type")
    @Expose
    private String event_type;

    public ResponsePojo(String fileData, String device_id, String lat, String lng, String speed, String event_type) {
        this.fileData = fileData;
        this.device_id = device_id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.event_type = event_type;
    }

    public String getFileDatasmall() {
        return fileData;
    }

    public void setFileDatasmall(String fileDatasmall) {
        this.fileData = fileDatasmall;
    }

    public String getDevice_id() {
        return device_id;
    }

    public void setDevice_id(String device_id) {
        this.device_id = device_id;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getEvent_type() {
        return event_type;
    }

    public void setEvent_type(String event_type) {
        this.event_type = event_type;
    }
```

Bellow Send Button Click Method ,When i click time upload all data save to server

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BaseUrl).client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())).build();


    API api = builder.create(API.class);

    //create file which we want to send to server.
    File videoFIle = new File(String.valueOf(realUri));
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), videoFIle);
    MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileData", videoFIle.getName(), requestBody);

    Call<ResponsePojo> call = api.submitData(image, "1, ", "4.667566", "54.54448", "5457", "2",image);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePojo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePojo> call, Response<ResponsePojo> response) {
            ResponsePojo body = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("Code "+response.message()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePojo> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

[Postman send request method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP4Pw.png)

Comment: Can you check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap) and do changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 404 not found web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059026/retrofit-404-not-found-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

For this instance,a 404 means there is no API for this URL.

Maybe, your URL needs to be `http://192.168.0.105/register/` 
instead of `http://192.168.0.105/register` or maybe it is malformed.
Example, `http://192.168.0.105//register/`

Answer (score 0):

This error basically related to the path(@Path) in some cases. so please check your request path just like @Path("/event").

According to the response code, the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

So, in this case, should check path and parameter what are we sending.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@POST` and want to send data using `@part` you need to first convert it to `RequestBody` before sending it. Do the following changes

In request code

```
Call<ResponsePojo> submitData(@Part MultipartBody.Part video,
                              @Part("device_id") RequestBody device_id,...
```

Before calling this method you need to convert your parameter to Requestbody

```
RequestBody device_id = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
        device_id);
```

Now use this variable as mentioned above in method call.